# Touch events not get triggered on SVG document

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, svg

Touch events do not get triggered on SVG document when a USE element has been used to draw a shape(via, xlink:href). The USE element references another element and indicates that the graphical content of the element is drawn here. However, touch events get triggered on the document in the absence of USE element.

Can anyone help me if am doing anything wrong?

This example shows the working touch events: http://jsfiddle.net/qGWQj
This examples doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/5gAPn/1

The problem happens on the iPad using iOS 4.3.5.

Comment: What browser/environment are you talking about? Could you show us a sample? Maybe on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: iPad OS : 4.3.5, Browser: safari 3,
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qGWQj/ 
SVG touch event problem example: http://jsfiddle.net/5gAPn/1/

Comment: I took the liberty to update your question to make that information more accessible. Unfortunately I don't know anything about iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Sauer for updating my question. Can you please recommend any forum where i can get more information about the iPad?